# Python Unicode Conversions

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding, python-unicode

How to do the following conversions in Python?

```
"杭州" to "%BA%BC%D6%DD"
"大连" to "%B4%F3%C1%AC"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert `u'杭州'` to `'%BA%BC%D6%DD'`:

```
In [24]: ''.join('%{0:X}'.format(ord(c)) for c in u"杭州".encode('gbk'))
Out[24]: '%BA%BC%D6%DD'

In [25]: ''.join('%{0:X}'.format(ord(c)) for c in u"大连".encode('gbk'))
Out[25]: '%B4%F3%C1%AC'
```

---

To convert `'%BA%BC%D6%DD'` to `u'杭州'`:

```
In [54]: import binascii    
In [55]: print(binascii.unhexlify(''.join('%BA%BC%D6%DD'.split('%'))).decode('gbk'))
杭州
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. it works. could you please teach me how to convert strings like '%BA%BC%D6%DD' back to u"杭州"?

Comment: @jack: I've added a way to convert `'%BA%BC%D6%DD'` back to `u"杭州"`. Note however that Dietrich Epp provided a better answer (using `urllib.parse.quote` and/or `urllib.parse.unquote`) if your Python version is modern enough (e.g. Python3).

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to give us more information.

```
def encode(s):
    if s == "杭州":
        return "%BA%BC%D6%DD"
    if s == "大连":
        return "%B4%F3%C1%AC"
    raise ValueError
```

You need to tell us the encoding you're using, for one thing.

```
import urllib.parse
def encode(s):
    return urllib.parse.quote(s.encode('gbk'))
```